# Past perfect usage in chronological stentences

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I had eaten breakfast before I went to work.

Why do we use past perfect here since that sentence is chronological?

Comment: Very few speakers of American English would use the past perfect there unless they really wanted to emphasize the sequence of events for some particular reason, perhaps as part of a longer explanation or tale.   *I normally ate breakfast at the cafeteria at work. The food was quite good. But that day, I'd eaten breakfast before I came to work because ...*

Comment: Because it is talking about a time before the past event (went to work). This tense is often preferred when relating a story. It talks about events which happened before the past events in the story.  You wouldn't use this in an ordinary conversation about something that happened recently.  The simple past is used: For example "I ate breakfast before I came to work this morning".